# How to find the gradient of grid-less data in python?

Tags: python, gradient

I have a pandas data frame containing location data (x_m and y_m) and another variable represented by the color bar in the figure.

[Sample figure showing the data points and a possible gradient arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un3WI.png)

How can I obtain the average gradient of all of the data points in my data set? I drew one of the possible solutions showing the gradient vector.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I ended up using scipy.interpolate.griddata, similar to what was done here: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/12057/how-to-interpolate-scattered-data-to-a-regular-grid-in-python

Comment: Something like scattered interpolation might help.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @Trilarion! I believe that I used something similar to what you suggested, so I'll edit my question